# Empty route for mobile hotspot fedora 37

Tags: centos

Periodically I have a mobile hotspot broken down with my laptop.

"Network is unreachable"

```
ip route show default
```

shows nothing.

As I understand I need to add default gateway to the interface

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.254 wl0ss20f3
```

But how do I understand which gw uses my smarthone mobile hotspot?

What is here?

route add default gw ??? wlp0s20f3